# CardLayout's Show Method Not Doing Anything

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager, cardlayout

So I just started practicing `CardLayout`, but I can't seem to get it to work. I look at over 10 sites, and I seem to be doing the same thing as them, but for some reason my version isn't working. The `next()` method is working fine, but calling `show()` doesn't do anything.

```
private static CardLayout cards;
private static JPanel panel;

private Main() {
    super("Card Layout");
    setBounds(0, 0, 500, 500);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(3);

    panel = new JPanel();

    add(panel);

    cards = new CardLayout();

    JPanel p1 = new JPanel();
    p1.setBackground(Color.WHITE);

    JPanel p2 = new JPanel();
    p2.setBackground(Color.BLACK);

    JPanel p3 = new JPanel();
    p3.setBackground(Color.RED);

    JPanel p4 = new JPanel();
    p4.setBackground(Color.BLUE);

    panel.add("white", p1);
    panel.add("black", p2);
    panel.add("red", p3);
    panel.add("blue", p4);

    panel.setLayout(cards);

    // cards.next(panel); This works fine for me.
    cards.show(panel, "red");

    setVisible(true);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new Main();
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are many problems with the code you posted, but the reason it is not working is simply the wrong order of your code. Before adding components to the `JPanel`, you need to set its layout manager. Also, you are invoking the wrong `add()` method. Only add the `JPanel` with the `CardLayout` to its parent container after you have added its contained `JPanel`s.

Apart from that, the code you posted doesn't compile because class `Main` obviously extends `JFrame` but that is missing in the code you posted.

Here is your code corrected.

```java
import java.awt.CardLayout;
import java.awt.Color;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Main extends JFrame {
    private static CardLayout cards;
    private static JPanel panel;

    private Main() {
        super("Card Layout");
        setBounds(0, 0, 500, 500);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(3);

        panel = new JPanel();
        cards = new CardLayout();
        panel.setLayout(cards);

        JPanel p1 = new JPanel();
        p1.setBackground(Color.WHITE);

        JPanel p2 = new JPanel();
        p2.setBackground(Color.BLACK);

        JPanel p3 = new JPanel();
        p3.setBackground(Color.RED);

        JPanel p4 = new JPanel();
        p4.setBackground(Color.BLUE);

        panel.add(p1, "white");
        panel.add(p2, "black");
        panel.add(p3, "red");
        panel.add(p4, "blue");

        // cards.next(panel); This works fine for me.
        cards.show(panel, "red");
        add(panel);

        setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Main();
    }
}
```

I recommend the tutorial [Creating a GUI With JFC/Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/index.html)

Comment: Thanks, but if I didn't set the layout to card layout before adding the stuff and how did the next method work fine? Also, both versions of the add method for the panel works for me. Does one of them have some advantage over the other? One last question, can the JFrame become card layout?

Comment: I used the code in the example that is in the tutorial that I gave a link to in my answer.